# XCode 7 on 10.10.3

Tags: macos, xcode

I've got a MacBook Pro with 10.10.3 on it. For reasons beyond my control I am unable to update to anything above 10.10.3 (critical software needed for work broken on 10.10.4 and above, dev doesn't seem to be interested in fixing it).

I would like to be able to install XCode 7 (need iOS 9 SDK) on that machine. What is the most recent version of XC7 that works on 10.10.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run Xcode 7 on that version of OS X.  The minimum system requirement, [according to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html) is 10.10.4.

> Xcode 7 requires a Mac running OS X version 10.10.4 or later.